# Using Strapi for microservice scenarios

Tags: microservices, strapi

I'd like to use Strapi for a project in which it is required to separate API for user accounts and their confidential data into a separate microservice.

Are there any significant problems of using Strapi in microservice scenarios? Is there anything against connecting multiple Strapi instances with eg. RabbitMQ to synchronize content?

I'm looking for a "clean" way to achieve such modularization with Strapi, so for instance I can make sure that there won't be any issues with cache refresh, etc.

Comment: I think you can design each microservice to handle specific functionalities, utilize shared databases or APIs for communication, and implement event-driven architecture for seamless integration...